# Strange texture error in font rendering

Tags: macos, opengl, text, glsl

I am following a tutorial from wikibooks: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Modern_OpenGL_Tutorial_Text_Rendering_01

Running on OSX 10.9 and Xcode5 installed on a rMBP with GT 650m, I can compile the sample code and render fine, but when I port the code to my SDL2 setup I get this:

[image: Block glyphs with blurry textures]

I know the shaders are correct because when I port them to the sample code I get text rendered correctly. It looks like the texture coordinates aren't correct, but I can't find the cause of it. One thing I noticed was if I change to OpenGL 3.2 core profile and fix the deprecated parts of the shaders, I get a fragment shader compile error due to the use of the tex sampler.

The complete code is included below:

```
// ============================================================================
// [Include Section]
// ============================================================================
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <iostream>

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_opengl.h>

#include <ft2build.h>
#include FT_FREETYPE_H

#include <unistd.h>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;

// ============================================================================
// [SdlApplication]
// ============================================================================
#define APPTITLE "SDL Template Program"
// SdlApplication is nothing more than thin wrapper to SDL library. You need
// just to instantiate it and call run() to enter the SDL event loop.

class OGL
{
public:
    OGL(){}
    ~OGL()
    {
        glDeleteProgram(shaderProgram);
        glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);
        glDeleteShader(vertexShader);

        glDeleteBuffers(1, &vbo);

        glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    }
public:
    SDL_GLContext context;
    GLuint fragmentShader, shaderProgram, vertexShader;
    GLuint vbo, vao;

    GLuint textProgram;
    GLint uniform_tex;
    GLint uniform_color;
    GLint attribute_coord;
};
struct SdlApplication
{
    SdlApplication();
    ~SdlApplication();

    // Application state (just convenience instead of 0, 1, ...).
    enum APP_STATE
    {
        APP_OK = 0,
        APP_FAILED = 1
    };

    // Initialize application, called by run(), don't call manually.
    int init(int width, int height);

    // Destroy application, called by destructor, don't call manually.
    void destroy();

    // Run application, called by your code.
    int run(int width, int height);

    // Called to process SDL event.
    void onEvent(SDL_Event* ev);

    void render_text(const char *text, float x, float y, float sx, float sy);

    // Called to render content into buffer.
    void Render();

    // Whether the application is in event loop.
    bool _running;
    SDL_Window *win;
    SDL_Renderer *renderer;
    SDL_GLContext context;

    OGL ogl;

    FT_Library ft;
    FT_Face face;
    GLuint vboText;

};

SdlApplication::SdlApplication() :
_running(false)
{
}

SdlApplication::~SdlApplication()
{

    destroy();
}


const GLchar* vTextSource =
"#version 120 \n"
"attribute vec2 coord;"
"varying vec2 texcoord;"
"void main(void) {"
"  gl_Position = vec4(coord.xy, 0, 1);"
"  texcoord = coord.xy;"
"}";

const GLchar* fTextSource =
"#version 120\n"
"varying vec2 texcoord;"
"uniform sampler2D tex;"
"uniform vec4 color;"
//"out vec4 outColor;"
"void main(void) {"
"  gl_FragColor= vec4(1,1,0,texture2D(tex, texcoord).a) * color;"
"}";

int SdlApplication::init(int width, int height)
{
    SDL_version compiled, linked;

    SDL_VERSION(&compiled);
    SDL_GetVersion(&linked);

    cout << "Compiled: " << compiled.major << "." << compiled.minor << endl;
    cout << "Linked: " << linked.major << "." << linked.minor << endl;
    SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_VIDEO_HIGHDPI_DISABLED, "0");

    // Initialize the SDL library.
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_TIMER) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "SDL_Init() failed: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return APP_FAILED;
    }
/*
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 2);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);
 */
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 24);

    win = SDL_CreateWindow(APPTITLE, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, width, height, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HIGHDPI);


    context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(win);

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();
    int w, h;
    SDL_GL_GetDrawableSize(win, &w, &h);
    std::cout << "Drawable:" << w << "x" << h << std::endl;



    //initialize freetype
    if (FT_Init_FreeType(&ft))
        assert(false && "FreeType init failure");

    if (FT_New_Face(ft, "DroidSerif-Regular.ttf", 0, &face))
        assert(false && "Could not open font");

    auto checkShader = [](GLint shader)
    {
        GLint compile_ok = GL_FALSE;
        glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compile_ok);
        if (compile_ok == GL_FALSE) {
            cout << "failed to compile shader\n";
            glDeleteShader(shader);
            exit(0);
        }
    };

    //create font program
    // Create and compile the vertex shader
    GLint vShader, fShader;
    vShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vShader, 1, &vTextSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vShader);
    checkShader(vShader);
    cout << "Vertex shader compiled ok\n";

    // Create and compile the fragment shader
    fShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fShader, 1, &fTextSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fShader);
    checkShader(fShader);
    cout << "Fragment shader compiled ok\n";

    // Link the vertex and fragment shader into a shader program
    ogl.textProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(ogl.textProgram, vShader);
    glAttachShader(ogl.textProgram, fShader);
    glLinkProgram(ogl.textProgram);
    assert(ogl.textProgram);

    //get attrib, get uniform
    ogl.attribute_coord = glGetAttribLocation(ogl.textProgram, "coord");
    ogl.uniform_tex = glGetUniformLocation(ogl.textProgram, "tex");
    ogl.uniform_color = glGetUniformLocation(ogl.textProgram, "color");

    if(ogl.attribute_coord == -1 || ogl.uniform_tex == -1 || ogl.uniform_color == -1)
        return 0;

    glGenBuffers(1, &vboText);

    // Success.
    return APP_OK;
}

void SdlApplication::destroy()
{
    if (win)
    {
        SDL_DestroyWindow(win);
        //SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
        SDL_GL_DeleteContext(context);
        SDL_Quit();
    }
}
struct point {
    GLfloat x;
    GLfloat y;
    GLfloat s;
    GLfloat t;
};
/**
 * Render text using the currently loaded font and currently set font size.
 * Rendering starts at coordinates (x, y), z is always 0.
 * The pixel coordinates that the FreeType2 library uses are scaled by (sx, sy).
 */
void SdlApplication::render_text(const char *text, float x, float y, float sx, float sy) {
    const char *p;
    FT_GlyphSlot g = face->glyph;

    /* Create a texture that will be used to hold one "glyph" */
    GLuint tex;

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glGenTextures(1, &tex);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
    glUniform1i(ogl.uniform_tex, 0);

    /* We require 1 byte alignment when uploading texture data */
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

    /* Clamping to edges is important to prevent artifacts when scaling */
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    /* Linear filtering usually looks best for text */
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    /* Set up the VBO for our vertex data */
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(ogl.attribute_coord);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboText);
    glVertexAttribPointer(ogl.attribute_coord, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    /* Loop through all characters */
    for (p = text; *p; p++) {
        /* Try to load and render the character */
        if (FT_Load_Char(face, *p, FT_LOAD_RENDER))
            continue;

        /* Upload the "bitmap", which contains an 8-bit grayscale image, as an alpha texture */
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_ALPHA, g->bitmap.width, g->bitmap.rows, 0, GL_ALPHA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, g->bitmap.buffer);

        /* Calculate the vertex and texture coordinates */
        float x2 = x + g->bitmap_left * sx;
        float y2 = -y - g->bitmap_top * sy;
        float w = g->bitmap.width * sx;
        float h = g->bitmap.rows * sy;

        point box[4] = {
            {x2, -y2, 0, 0},
            {x2 + w, -y2, 1, 0},
            {x2, -y2 - h, 0, 1},
            {x2 + w, -y2 - h, 1, 1},
        };

        /* Draw the character on the screen */
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof box, box, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

        /* Advance the cursor to the start of the next character */
        x += (g->advance.x >> 6) * sx;
        y += (g->advance.y >> 6) * sy;
    }

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(ogl.attribute_coord);
    glDeleteTextures(1, &tex);
}

int SdlApplication::run(int width, int height)
{
    // Initialize application.
    int state = init(width, height);
    if (state != APP_OK) return state;

    // Enter to the SDL event loop.
    SDL_Event ev;
    _running = true;

    while (SDL_WaitEvent(&ev))
    {
        onEvent(&ev);
        //Render();
        //SDL_GL_SwapWindow(win);
        if (_running == false)
        {
            break;
        }

        //glUseProgram(ogl.shaderProgram);
        //  glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);


        //render text
        float sx = 2.0 / width;
        float sy = 2.0 / height;

    glUseProgram(ogl.textProgram);
        /* White background */
        glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    /* Enable blending, necessary for our alpha texture */
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    GLfloat black[4] = { 0, 0, 0, 1 };
    GLfloat red[4] = { 1, 0, 0, 1 };
    GLfloat transparent_green[4] = { 0, 1, 0, 0.5 };

    FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face, 0, 48);
    glUniform4fv(ogl.uniform_color, 1, black);

        render_text("The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog", -1 + 8 * sx, 1 - 50 * sy, sx, sy);
        render_text("The Misaligned Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog", -1 + 8.5 * sx, 1 - 100.5 * sy, sx, sy);

        /* Scaling the texture versus changing the font size */
        render_text("The Small Texture Scaled Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog", -1 + 8 * sx, 1 - 175 * sy, sx * 0.5, sy * 0.5);
        FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face, 0, 24);
        render_text("The Small Font Sized Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog", -1 + 8 * sx, 1 - 200 * sy, sx, sy);
        FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face, 0, 48);
        render_text("The Tiny Texture Scaled Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog", -1 + 8 * sx, 1 - 235 * sy, sx * 0.25, sy * 0.25);
        FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face, 0, 12);
        render_text("The Tiny Font Sized Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog", -1 + 8 * sx, 1 - 250 * sy, sx, sy);
        FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face, 0, 48);

        /* Colors and transparency */
        render_text("The Solid Black Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog", -1 + 8 * sx, 1 - 430 * sy, sx, sy);

        glUniform4fv(ogl.uniform_color, 1, red);
        render_text("The Solid Red Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog", -1 + 8 * sx, 1 - 330 * sy, sx, sy);
        render_text("The Solid Red Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog", -1 + 28 * sx, 1 - 450 * sy, sx, sy);

        glUniform4fv(ogl.uniform_color, 1, transparent_green);
        render_text("The Transparent Green Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog", -1 + 8 * sx, 1 - 380 * sy, sx, sy);
        render_text("The Transparent Green Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog", -1 + 18 * sx, 1 - 440 * sy, sx, sy);
        SDL_GL_SwapWindow(win);
    }

    return APP_OK;
}

void SdlApplication::onEvent(SDL_Event* ev)
{
    switch (ev->type)
    {
        case SDL_QUIT:
            _running = false;
            break;

        case SDL_KEYDOWN:
        {
            if (ev->key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE)
            {
                _running = false;
            }
        }
    }
}

void SdlApplication::Render()
{}


// ============================================================================
// [Entry-Point]
// ============================================================================

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    SdlApplication app;
    return app.run(640, 480);
}
```

Comment: It's difficult to say without the shader source what the problem could be.  I only see one glVertexAttribPointer call though, so you're only setting up one attribute, even though you have two attribute values (position and texture coordinates).  Perhaps you're trying to stuff both of them into a single vec4?

Comment: The shader source code is just above the init function. And you're right, it is using that one vec4 for both position and texture coordinates. I had mistakenly changed it to a vec2 and had them both set to using .xy, but the texture coord should be .zw. Once I made the changes it works as expected.